# Save Current DateTime in App Settings

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, app-config

Good day, Please i'm trying to save `DateTime` Value into an App Settings.

In my settings table i have `InstallationDate` and `PreviousDate` as shown.

Name              |Type              |Scope       |Value

InstallationDate  - System.DateTime  -  User   -

PreviousDate     -  System.DateTime  -  User   -

I'm trying to insert an  `InstallationDate` on first run and `PreviousDate` on Form_Closing.

```
private void frmMainMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int firstU = Properties.Settings.Default.FirstUse;
        int one = 1;

        if (firstU == 0)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default["FirstUse"] = one;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }


        Properties.Settings.Default["InstallationDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

    } 


private void frmMainMenu_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default["PreviousDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

But the issues now is, its trowing an exception

> "The settings property 'InstallationDate' is of a non-compatible type."

Comment: Since you defined the property using `System.DateTime` type, you should assign `DateTime.Now` to property.

Comment: Or better, `DateTime.UtcNow`...

Answer (score 4):

You write:

```
Properties.Settings.Default["InstallationDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

You say `InstallationDate` is a `DateTime`, but you try to set a `string` (using `ToShortDateString`) in the field, hence the types don't match.

Comment: I just change, and it didn't trow an exception, but the value DateTime isn't saving into the App.Settings File.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type of the variable in the settings file to `System.DateTime` and it should work.

Comment: If you follow the suggestion to use `.UtcNow` you need to make sure you're consistently using UtcNow everywhere. Don't just change this one value. Given that you're new to winforms it is important you understand what setting UtcNow does, ie that it will actually save a different time (Coordinated Universal Time) than you might be expecting and, why that is a good thing. You will also need to update your UI wherever that value is displayed to a user to convert the UTC time back into local time for users of your winforms application.